# need to validate two fields, by numeric value inputted

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two fields that a user will fill in, one is a begin date, the other is the end date.

I want to alert the user if the end date is less than the begin date.

The values will be in this format: YYYYMMDD (20101209)

So I need this to fire an alert (if the begin date is greater than the end date) to the user once both fields are filled in, so it won't alert them until both fields are filled in.

Also, these two fields are hidden fields, because I am using the altFormat, altField of jQuery's datepicker.

the id and name's of the hidden fields are: begin_date, end_date

Also need help firing the function after both fields are filled.

Comment: Could you not do if(end_date.value - begin_date.value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function compareDates(d1, d2) {
    var date1 = new Date(d1);
    var date2 = new Date(d2);

    if(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
        alert("Start Date is greater than End Date");
    }
}
```

There may be a shorter way, I'm no JS expert.

Answer (score 0):

Make a KeyValuePair Class. Pseudocode follows:

```
class Datepair
{
    private int m_begindate;
    private int m_enddate;

    public Datepair(int begin, int end)
    {
        if (begin > end)
        {
            throw new Exception("Your startdate is later than your enddate")
        }
        else
        {
            m_enddate = end;
            m_begindate = begin;
        }
    }
}
```

Have both fields call the same update method and write to the Datepair once both fields contain something.

```
public void OnFieldUpdate(){
    if (Field1.hasentrie && Field2.hasentrie)
    {
        try
        {
            myDatepair = new Datepair(Field1.Value, Field2.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this looks an awful lot like C# - but something like that might work